# SOAP - dummy DAO

Tags: web-services, soap

what is the best way to fake a soap web service call?  I want to integrate my webservice call in the later part of implementation, when the third party webserver is ready.  Should I use a dummy DAO class or create a dummy WSDL and use it? 
Any suggestions?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Use a mocking framework to create a fake client OR use Fiddler to return the response you need.  I don't see how a dummy WSDL helps you.

Comment: I don't have any webserver in place currently, so want to fake only a webserver and not client.  Fiddler or Soap UI would need a WSDL to mock the request..  So, i understand the only way is a webserver and publishing it . then consume that service in my client code.. is that correct?

Comment: Wrong.  You can have Fiddler return the desired response if you send a request to a URL of your choosing.  It's quite useful.

Comment: Can you share some links, that i can follow?

Comment: Fiddler docs are my best recommendation.